# Resolving UNC path using hosts file

Tags: windows, hosts

I'm having a problem accessing a UNC path in Windows Server 2008 using the hosts file.

My hosts file looks like:

```
10.x.x.x     server_1
```

When trying to access the unc path:

**This works:**

```
\\10.x.x.x\data
```

**This doesn't work and says "Windows cannot find \\server_1\data")**

```
\\server_1\data
```

Does anyone know how to make it resolve the path using a hosts file?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but "server_1" in your `\\server_1` example isn't actually a domain name, so it wouldn't go "trough" your hosts file, would it?

Answer (score 4):

I found [this article that explains what you can do to make aliases for localhost's UNC path](http://blog.malevy.net/2010/05/creating-netbios-alias-for-local.html). I was having a similar problem to the one you are having and did as the article explained, with a succesful result.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and this worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
10.x.x.x     server_1
```

to `%SYSTEM32%\drivers\etc\LMHOSTS`

(Note this file doesn't exist by default)

LMHOSTS is to unc paths as HOSTS is to TPC/IP paths.

More info here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959846.aspx

Comment: In both my `hosts` and `lmhosts` file I have: `127.0.0.1  whatever`. When I try to run `dir \\whatever\C$\temp` I get: `The user name or password is incorrect.`. Any idea why? When I use an IP it works fine with no prompt for password: `dir \\127.0.0.1\C$\temp`

Comment: I get the same error as @Kip. I'm guessing there's something in our network security preventing this because the request and actual server names don't match. I just wish I knew how to make a security exception for this one test machine.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hosts file for resolving the hostname?
You might try **removing the underscore**: change `server_1` to `server1` or `server-1`. It used to be that underscores are invalid characters in system and domain names. Perhaps that's changed (although I've yet to see some underscore in the domain part of a website), but give it a try in any case.

Comment: Hi, I tried removing the underscore but its still not working. I am pretty sure it is not a name problem because I can call webservices with that name. For example: `http://server_1/mywebservice/service.asmx` works fine. But when using UNC file paths, it doesn't seem to be using the hosts file to resolve the name=/